# Unique random no numbers in python with the Secrets module

Tags: python, random-seed

I need a high precision unique random number generated every time a while loop cycles quickly.  I am using less than 5000 integer from Secrets python module then multiplying it by .001 to get a smaller random number.   The issue is, in my output there are often sections of repeating random numbers.  Is there a way to prevent this without checking for them and reiterating the generation?  Is this in regards to the system clock?

Comment: Show us your code.  The random number algorithm in Python repeats every 2**19937 numbers, which would take longer than the life of the universe to repeat.  You must be "unrandomizing" it with your processing.

Comment: Thanks Tim,  I found that it was actully other elements of my code, but ultimately I really like the secrets random generator.  for example...   secretsGenerator.uniform(0.001, RatePercent)